# Adding days to Date in javascript / typescript gives completely wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, typescript

I have this very simple code, and it works sometimes but other times it gives the complete wrong date:

```
  addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
    console.log('adding ' + days + ' days');
    console.log(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    console.log(date);
    return date;
  }
```

Here is an example of the output:

Works!

```
adding 7 days
error-chart.component.ts:118 Tue Aug 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
error-chart.component.ts:120 Tue Aug 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
```

Stops working:

```
adding 14 days
error-chart.component.ts:118 Tue Aug 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
error-chart.component.ts:120 Thu Mar 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Vest-Europa (normaltid))
```

somehow jumps 2 years

```
adding 14 days
error-chart.component.ts:118 Thu Jul 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
error-chart.component.ts:120 Thu Jun 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
```

now 4 years!

```
adding 14 days
error-chart.component.ts:118 Thu Jun 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
error-chart.component.ts:120 Thu Apr 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
```

Comment: There are an untold amount of JS date questions. Are you sure none of them answer this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well, I copied and pasted the answer from one of those questions. But still get a method that works 10% of the time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a problem with types. If `days` is 14, then it will yield 16th August correctly. However, if `days` is "14", then it will yield 2nd of March.

Solution:

```
  addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
    console.log('adding ' + days + ' days');
    console.log(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    console.log(date);
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: Typescript returns this error about 'days':  'Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.