# TypeScript add one day function

Tags: angular, date, typescript, angular2-template

I'm new to Angular 2 and TypeScript. I've changed from jQuery and I'm having some problems with some simple functions. Right now, I have an UI with two datepickers and I'm trying to autocomplete the second one once the first one changes (add one day). According to this [Adding days to Date in javascript / typescript gives completely wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718160/adding-days-to-date-in-javascript-typescript-gives-completely-wrong-date), and what I expects from JS, the code must be something like this:

```
updateEndDate(): void {
  this.endDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

I have a class which has the startDate and endDate parameters and the updateEndDate() methods is binding to the onChange() event of the startDate datepicker input.

When I try it out, I get this message in the console:

```
this.endDate.getDate is not a function at ItemTemplateComponent.webpackJsonp..
```

I think I'm doing something really wrong, but I don't know what. Does anybody knows what I'm missing?

EDIT:

I tryed with an auxiliary date parameter to check if there is something wrong with the function or with the parameter. I did this:

```
auxDate: Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.auxDate = new Date();
}

updateEndDate(): void {
  console.log(auxDate);
  this.auxDate.setDate(this.auxDate.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(auxDate);
}
```

And that worked fine. So my problem is with the parameter.

My class definition:

```
export class DateRange {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}
```

I set the startDate using a datepicker which sets "YYYY-MM-DD" format. Could be this be the problem?

---

UPDATE (A SOLUTION, NOT THE BEST WAY I THINK):

As I commented, the problem is that when using two-ways data binding to bind the startDate value (a Date) with the corresponding input type date in the template, the value of the input is understand as a string vy Angular2, not as a Date, so then, the updateEndDate() method crash.

The solution I found, but I think is not the best (I think there must be a way to apply two-ways data binding for dates) is to bind only the event onChange and convert the string into a date in the method updateEndDate() as:

In the template:

```
(change)="updateEndDate($event.target.value)"
```

In the component:

```
updateEndDate(dateValee: string): void {
this.endDate = new Date(dateValue);
... OTHER LINES
}
```

Now I'm having problems because the "new Date(dateValue)" is not giving me the correct date, but that's other problem (I think because of the GMT o a problem with some standard).

Comment: If there any special reason you do not want to use moment.js? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: I'm following the angular.io documentation, that's why. I've seen that when I set the date using the datepicker, the typeof startDate changes to string, and that's the reason of the problem. Why does happends and how to figure out with this?

Comment: I mean, it seems that I only can use the two-way data binding with some little type of data, like strings and numbers in some cases, but not with Date for example, is this correct? Or there is a way for doing this?

Comment: @user3368457 How are you binding `updateEndDate` to the `onChange` event?

Comment: The dates that come from your form are probably strings, not Date instances. Try to parse your dates again using "new Date" before calling any date method

Comment: I just use `(change)="updateEndDate()"` to bind the event onChange of the input type date with the method. The parameter startDate is bind in the two-ways data binding style as `[(ngModel)]="startDate"`. The problem is that the value of input type date is understood as a string, not as a date.

Comment: @lleon that was the problem, I solved it in the onChange event, but there is a way of binding directly the date value from the date picker? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could help, I used this statement to get the selected date
In html
`(change)="updateEndDate($event)"`

In ts

```js
updateEndDate(dateValee: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Event>){
 this.endDate= new Date(dateValue.value);
}
```